# Get the time of arrival for a wireless frame

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am implementing a TDMA-like wireless protocol in OMNET++ and INET. To synchronise with the time slot structure, a node needs to precisely retrieve the time of arrival of beacon frames. The **Signal** object that the radio is receiving has the **arrival** property that could be used for that, however only the associated **Packet** object is passed up the stack and it does not contain that information.

I suppose the right way of implementing that would be to associate a custom tag carrying the timing information with received packets. To do this, shall I override some classes in the radio/medium stack of INET or is there an out-of-the-box solution that I am overlooking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/pull/403) has been merged into INET master.